# Hide Google Map Maker Data on Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm wondering if there is anyway to hide or disable user-contributed bike lines/trails to Google Map Maker?

My website has a riding area where there is a bunch of bad/inaccurate map maker data shown when you toggle the map from Google Earth to Google Maps.
http://www.trailforks.com/riding_areas/cumberland

The data is visible here on Map maker.
http://goo.gl/Ebnq4

My site uses GPS data to map trails, where as this map maker data someone hand drew and we would like to hide it from the google maps we overlay our trail data on when in road view.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the style of the basemap, but not with perfect granularity.  In this case bike trails (and other trails/paths) are classified under Local Roads ... so if you don't mind losing those you can turn them off with a custom style.  For example if you pass mapOptions in while instantiating your map, you might do something like:

```
var mapOptions = {
 styles : [
    {
      featureType: "road.local",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, this does work but as you mentioned I also loose the local roads which I would like to keep. Too bad Google doesn't differentiate them.

Comment: File a feature request for more granularity (and this specific use case) at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles

Comment: this doesn't seem to hide ski runs at all anymore, I can't find ANY way to hide ski runs on the map!

Comment: Note if the data is bad on MapMaker, you can edit it directly there, and after moderation the corrected data will show up on the basemap.  That seems like the best solution?

Comment: Oh regarding the ski slopes no longer being under "roads" I'm going to research this, but meanwhile turning "all" off and then turning all the main categories may be a workaround.

Comment: hiding all doesn't seem to hide the ski runs.

Comment: Hiding "all" hides absolutely everything, including ski runs (I just tested). If you are finding differently please include link to a fiddle or other demo.

Comment: what is the syntax you are using to hide all?